# Does the XP bonus from the XP event stack with a Lucky Egg?

Tags: pokemon-go

The XP Event started Nov 23 UTC time. Do we get 4x the XP with the double XP event together with a lucky egg when we spin a Pokestop, catch a Pokemon, or evolve?

Or is it only 2x max?

Comment: Its on you to point out the feature is active; my understanding is it went live tomorrow, and your writing in future tense doesn't help that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48980/discussion-between-frank-and-).

Comment: @太極者無極而生 - Please don't lash out at other users. Frank may have high standards but that is not an excuse to target him with hateful comments. Also note that - should **any** user be targeting you with downvotes, the system will pick this up as abuse and remove the downvotes. I have edited some of your comments that provide clarifications to the post, and removed others that were blatantly rude and not needed.

Comment: @太極者無極而生 since the answer has a definitive answer, you should accept the answer so the question is marked as closed, unless there's something else that needs clarification

Comment: @Vemonus Accepting an answer doesn't mark it as closed.  Just that an answer has been accepted.

Comment: @Frank that's what I meant. Poor wording.

Answer (score 14):

Yes, you will get 4x experience if you use a Lucky Egg during this event!

Before using Lucky Egg:

[image]

After using Lucky Egg:

[image]

Comment: 600XP for a catch (with great throw)? that's better than an evolution before the event of 500XP!

Comment: @太極者無極而生 use a Lucky Egg before your first of the day bonus!

Comment: wow, use a lucky egg, and then first of the day Pokestop, first of the day catch, and 60 evolutions, and then claiming 10 gym bonuses... that will be a lot of XP and stardust

Comment: @太極者無極而生 yeah, even more if it's your 7th day in a row

Comment: hm... correction: to claim the gym bonus, there is no need do that during the use of a lucky egg, because gym bonus is for stardust and Poke coins, so while the event will double the stardust (making it 10,000 stardust for 10 gyms), the lucky egg only further double the XP and not useful for gym bonus